# Sound in Refresh controller

Tags: swift, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

So, I have standard refresh controller in my UITableViewController, which updates the data in table view.

```
 lazy var refresher: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = .lightGray
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    return refreshControl
}()

    @objc func refresh(){
    getMethod()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(500)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline){
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
    }
```

So I want to add the sound, when the user refresh starts, and the sound when the refresh finishes. The same as in Facebook or twitter apps. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with this simple solution. Start by importing `AVFoundation` on your class and add the audio(s) file to your project, by dragging them to xcode:

[image]

Then create a method to play a sound (if your files are not mp3 then change the `ofType` param value):

```
private var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound(soundFileName: String) {
    guard
        let urlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFileName, ofType: "mp3")
        else { return }
    
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)
    
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player?.prepareToPlay()
        player?.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Finally call the method when the refresh starts

```
@objc func refresh(){
    playSound(soundFileName: "refresh-start")
    getMethod()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(500)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline){
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

and when the refresh ends.

Comment: Thanks, it worked just fine!! Did not realize how easy it is.

Comment: Other question. How can I mute the sounds, if the phone is in silent mode?

Comment: @YessenYermukhanbet Have you tried running this code on a device in silent mode? I believe the sound won't be played.

Comment: Yeah, I have also downloaded it to my device, and tried to change it to silent mode. However, it is still playing that sounds. Form the web, it seems like it should have been muted, but it is not, weirdly.